# aggregate root with nested list to one table with fluent api

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have an aggregate root: `Report`.
This `Report` entity has a list of `Order` entities.

How do I save the `Report`, and get fluent api to insert one record in the database table for each order?

**Report Entity:** `{Orders, ReportId}`

**Order Entity:** `{Order Id, Total Price}`

to this DB Schema:

{ReportId, OrderId, TotalPrice}

Currently, I have to map files. One for order, and one for report. Both use `ToTable("MyTable");`, but the PK for the db table is actually OrderId.

So, I get an error that `Report` doesn't have a PK, which is right, it's PK is each order ID.

I tried this, which failed because `Orders` is a list: 
`HasKey(report=> report.Orders.OrderId)`

**EDIT**

```
public class ReportMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Report>
{
  public ReportMap()
  {
     Property( br => br.ReportId ).HasColumnName( "FFReportId" );
     Property( br => br.ReportDate ).HasColumnName( "FFBatchDate" );
     HasRequired( br => br.Orders );

     ToTable( "FFReport" );
  }
}


public class OrderMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
{
  public OrderMap()
  {
     HasKey( o => o.OrderId);
     Property( o => o.OrderId).HasColumnName( "OrderId" );

     ToTable( "FFReport" );
  }
```

}

Error I'm getting is Report doesn't have a PK listed, but it's PK(s) are each of the OrderIds in it's collection

Comment: It would help if you posted: 1- your mapping code for these entities. 2- the code for the entities 3- the code you use to create a new report and associated orders. Also I fail to see how your DB Schema matches your entities. You list 3 columns for your schema, are we to assume this is for 1 table? You have 2 entities, why not post schema information for 2 tables (or however you have it mapped back).

Comment: @Igor Two entities -> 1 table.

Comment: Seems like a bad design. You have a root type (Report) with a collection of dependencies (Orders). In a relational DB design this would translate into 2 tables with a one to many relationship. Otherwise you are modeling in the DB based only on [first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), usually you want to be at least [3rd normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form).

Comment: yep, I agree. But back to the question, is it possible to get fluent api to map to my bad database schema without an intermediate flattened model?

Comment: I doubt it, I do not believe that EF relational mapping was designed around 1NF structures and use multiple relational models. If you wanted to not change the schema then the best option would be to create a new model that completely reflects the single table as you have it in your schema.